# Default.aspx default root

Tags: page-layout, site

Im trying to figure out how can I edit the default.aspx page.
Where the default.aspx for the root web is stored ?

And how can i programmatically add a webpart to it?

What is the diference in using Modules to store pages X using _Layout directory?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There may be times when you may want to deploy files to the SharePoint
>   server regardless of their file type, such as new master pages. To do
>   this, you can use Modules (not to be confused with Visual Basic code
>   modules). Modules are containers for files in a SharePoint solution.
>   When the solution is deployed, the files in the module are copied to
>   the specified folders on the SharePoint server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231567(v=vs.100).aspx

all about webparts that you would need to know~!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231579.aspx

adding a webpart to a page is complex:

```
    public void AddWebPartToPage(SPWeb web, string pageUrl, string zoneID, int zoneIndex)
    {
        using (SPLimitedWebPartManager manager = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(pageUrl, PersonalizationScope.Shared))
        {
                VisualWebPart1.httpRedirectHome.httpRedirectHome redirectme = new VisualWebPart1.httpRedirectHome.httpRedirectHome();
                manager.AddWebPart(redirectme, zoneID, zoneIndex);

        }
    }
```

the above is a method i made to add a webpart to a given page...

to understand what im doing! `VisualWebPart1.httpRedirectHome.httpRedirectHome` that is my visual webpart that im creating in a new object:

so create your visual webpart.

if you were to create a feature that is in the same project and have an event handler attached to it, within the event you call that method:

```
    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    { 
        //when the feature is activated call this method
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
        {
           using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
           {
              //get the current web object to pass along, give the url, its webpart zone and its zone index
              AddWebPartToPage(web,SPContext.Current.Site.Url + "/mysubsite/default.aspx",0,"Main",0)
           }
        }
    }

    public void AddWebPartToPage(SPWeb web, string pageUrl, string zoneID, int zoneIndex)
    {
        using (SPLimitedWebPartManager manager = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(pageUrl, PersonalizationScope.Shared))
        {
                VisualWebPart1.httpRedirectHome.httpRedirectHome redirectme = new VisualWebPart1.httpRedirectHome.httpRedirectHome();
                manager.AddWebPart(redirectme, zoneID, zoneIndex);

        }
    }
```

SPLimitedWebPartManager

> Provides a limited set of Web Part operations that can be performed in
>   object model scenarios when there is no HttpContext and no
>   instantiated Page object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.splimitedwebpartmanager_members.aspx

Comment: lol its fine! happy to help!